# How to remove button hover property upon clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've seen a lot of post with almost the same problem as mine but it is not working for me.

I would like to remove the hover property of my button upon clicking the said button before the remove event I have.

Edit: I have 3 buttons for this.

Edi2: I found a workaround for this. I manually set the button color upon clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click', function() { // when you click the button
  $(this).addClass('no-hover-button'); // add the class 'no-hover-button'
});

button:not(.no-hover-button):hover { /* only apply hover styling when the button does not have the class 'no-hover-button' */
  color: red;
}
```

like in your case

```
.btn-group button:not(.no-hover-button):hover {
  background-color: #FFF6C3;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: Do you have another way?

What I'm currently getting is after clicking the button the alert will pop and the hover effect will be removed when my pointer is outside the button.

What I like to do is after clicking the button, the hover effect will be removed even if my mouse pointer is still in the button (and the alert will still pop).

Comment: can you create a fiddle and help me know what exactly you want?

Comment: Hi. I just did a workaround to manually set the button color in the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change or alter the actual :hover selector through Javascript.However, you can add an another class (new) and remove that class(new) onClick.